# WordPress not linking correctly with .htaccess redirect to subdirectory

Tags: redirect, htaccess, directory

I have read other posts about redirect to subdirectory issues, but they don't answer this precise question. I would like to redirect the main domain name in a hosting account into a subdirectory. The subdirectory contains a clone of the original site.

I have a client that is on a web host that I don't have much experience with. The redirect page says, "Wild Card Redirect box will redirect all files within a directory to the same filename in the redirected directory. You cannot use a Wild Card Redirect to redirect your main domain to a different directory on your site."

So, I added code right into .htaccess to redirect the domain name into the subdirectory. The home page works fine, but all the links go back out to the original files. (I added a test comment in header.php so I can tell which version I'm in.)

Would the fix be to change the address in WordPress too? It seems to me that if the domain is aimed at the subdirectory, no further action should be needed inside WordPress.

Comment: To clarify, this is an external “redirect”, ie. the URL changes to include the `/subdirectory`? And the links that that go back to the original files don’t include this subdirectory?

Comment: That is a good clarification. I would like the subdirectory not to show in the address. I'm cleaning up a file structure with a lot of extraneous stuff. The WordPress directories and files are mixed in with all that stuff.